# Blender on Linux starting, but not showing a window

Tags: linux

Blender 3.2.1 starts without crashing and runs, but doesn't actually open a window. It shows a window preview of the default start screen, but the actual window does not appear.

I am running pop!_OS 22.04. I tried installing blender from the official repos, via flathub and downloading from the official website and get the same behavior. Graphics drivers are installed and working correctly, and I don't get this behavior with any other applications. What could be the Issue here?

Edit:
Starting blender from terminal, with or without sudo, does not return any errors or warnings

Comment: Is it possible it’s appearing on another desktop/workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the window was appearing on a screen that was connected but turned off. I feel kinda stupid now

Comment: I was starting to think how that was even possible aside from the possibility as mentioned by TheLabCat. But glad you figured it out :)